# webMethod not working in vs2015

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, visual-studio-2015, webmethod

I made a simple example web project (using vs 2015 Empty template) which has a a very simple WebMethod in it. But it's not working no matter what I try.
The idea is that when you scroll the page to the bottom it calls the web method, but the ajax call always fails.

**Code behind:**

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Services
Imports System.Web.Services

Public Class deafult
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod, ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>
    Public Shared Function Gettime() As String
        Return Now.ToShortDateString
    End Function
End Class
```

**Designer Code:**

```
    <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="deafult.aspx.vb" Inherits="test2.deafult" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="height:750px; background: red">
    <br /><br />

    </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            GetRecords();
        }
    });
    function GetRecords() {


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "default.aspx/Getime",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert('failed');
            }
        });
    }
    function OnSuccess(response) {
        alert('done');

    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Web Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do you get an error in browser console?

Comment: no errors in the console, just get the "failed" alert from the ajax error function

Comment: change your error to and see what is it: error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  alert(xhr.responseText);
}

Comment: Did that and get a 404 ...resource cannot be found , requested url: default.aspx/Gettime

Comment: do you by any chance have url rewriting enabled?

Comment: Nope, not that i know of...not even sure how to do that. By the way thanks for your help !

Comment: np, can you make an asmx service and put your webmethod there and see if you still get 404: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/webservices/web_services_examples.htm